# How to play a sound with Rebol 2 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, terminal, rebol, rebol2

The feature that is missing is to play sound. I'm thinking of calling a system library or a terminal command that would accept the sound name as a parameter.

The goal is to get some sound from, for example, a button click.

PS. I'm using Rebol/view on an iBook G3 with Mac OS X Panther.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Rebol [sound port](http://www.rebol.com/docs/sound.html) (`sound://`) isn't supported on MacOS / OSX.

Two workarounds that come to mind:

1) Basic terminal bell

```
prin #"^G"
```

2) `call` out to a sound tool like [`afplay`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/afplay.1.html)

```
call [afplay %/System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff]
```

Comment: Afplay is not available with Panther.

Comment: @felix - You need to use whatever audio/sound systems Panther comes with.  I do recall people calling Applescript/iTunes via [osascript](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html)